# How to calculate ratios for an additive attribute with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Using the sample mongodb aggregation collection (http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json), I would like to output the population share of every city in California.

In SQL, it could look like this:

```
SELECT city, population/SUM(population) as poppct
FROM (
    SELECT city, SUM(population) as population
    FROM zipcodes
    WHERE state='CA'
    GROUP BY city
) agg group by state;
```

This can be done using mongodb map/reduce:

```
db.runCommand({
   mapreduce : "zipcodes"
   , out : { inline : 1}
   , query : {state: "CA"}
   , map : function() { 
       emit(this.city, this.pop); 
       cache.totalpop = cache.totalpop || 0; 
       cache.totalpop += this.pop; 
     }
   , reduce : function(key, values) {
       var pop = 0;
       values.forEach(function(value) {
          if (value && typeof value == 'number' && value > 0) pop += value;
       });
       return pop;
     }
   , finalize: function(key, reduced) {
       return reduced/cache.totalpop;
     }
   , scope: { cache: { } }
});
```

Can this be also achieved using the new aggregation framework (v2.2)?  This would require some form of global scope, as in the map/reduce case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
db.zipcodes.remove();
db.zipcodes.insert([
    { city:"birmingham", population:1500000, state:"AL" },
    { city:"London", population:10000, state:"ON" },
    { city:"New York", population:1000, state:"NY" },
    { city:"Denver", population:100, state:"CO" },
    { city:"Los Angeles", population:1000000, state:"CA" },
    { city:"San Francisco", population:2000000, state:"CA" },
]);

db.zipcodes.runCommand("aggregate", { pipeline: [
    { $match: { state: "CA" } }, // WHERE state='CA'
    { $group: {
        _id: "$city",            // GROUP BY city
        population: { $sum: "$population" }, // SUM(population) as population
    }},
]});
```

produces

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                "_id" : "San Francisco",
                "population" : 2000000
            },
            {
                "_id" : "Los Angeles",
                "population" : 1000000
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Cirrus, what I am after is (assuming San Francisco and LA are the only 2 cities in California):

    {
        "result" : [
            {
                "_id" : "San Francisco",
                "population_ratio" : .666667
            },
            {
                "_id" : "Los Angeles",
                "population_ratio" : .3333333
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
    }

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. I can't think how you could calculate that in the same AF pipeline, but I don't think I'd want to sum() that each time anyway. You might be better to calculate that on insert, cache and calculate the percentage in your app from the aggregate query population count above.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
db.zipcodes.group( { key: { state:1 } , 
                  reduce: function(curr, result) { 
                              result.total += curr.pop; 
                              result.city.push( { _id: curr.city, pop: curr.pop } ); }, 
                 initial: { total: 0, city:[] }, 
                 finalize: function (result) {
                              for (var idx in result.city ) {
                                 result.city[idx].ratio = result.city[idx].pop/result.total;
                               } 

                              } } )
```

Comment: Correct.  Thanks for posting this.  I was hoping to do the ratio calculation within an aggregation pipeline.